# Read Zipped and DES Encrypted File

Tags: python, encryption

I've been sent a data file which had been gzipped, and DES encrypted. I want to unencrypt it, and unzip it.

My code to decrypt the file looks like this

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

key = 'XXXXXXXX'
mode = DES.MODE_ECB
des = DES.new(key, mode)

input_file = r'C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Somefile.gz.des.20141001'

with open(input_file, 'rb') as file:
    ciphertext = file.read().replace('\n', ' ')

text = des.decrypt(ciphertext)

output_file = r'C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Somefile.gz.20141001'

with open(file_name, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(text)
```

The problem is that the output file doesn't appear to be decrypted properly, in that I can't subsequently unzip the file; it's not recognised as a gzipped file.

I've double, and triple checked, that I'm using the right key. What else might be going wrong?

Comment: why do you do this? `ciphertext = file.read().replace('\n', ' ')` ? that may or maynot be breaking things ... In that I doubt that spaces are replaced with new lines after its encrypted

Comment: Are you sure it is ECB and not CBC?

Answer (score 1):

with the information you have provided it is impossible to say what your problem or solution is ... that said I'll take a stab that this is your problem

```
with open(input_file, 'rb') as file:
    ciphertext = file.read().replace('\n', ' ')
    #I doubt that the original encryptor replaced spaces with newlines after they encrypted it

text = des.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

you may want to try

```
with open(input_file, 'rb') as file:
    ciphertext = file.read()

text = des.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

or

```
with open(input_file, 'rb') as file:
    ciphertext = file.read()

text = des.decrypt(ciphertext).replace("\n"," ")
```